# How to check if window is already open before opening a new one

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I am creating a window on click of a button. If I click the button more than once, it opens a window each time I click on it. How can I check first if the window is already open? If open close it and if not open a new one.

I am using following code to show window using extjs.

```
var modiwin = Ext.create('widget.window', {
    height: 70,
    width: 110,
    title: 'Editing',
    closable: true,
    autoScroll: false,
    collapsible: true,
    //modal:'True',
    maximizable: false,
    resizable:false,
    items: [mdsavebtn,mddelbtn]
});
modiwin.setPosition(175,55);
modiwin.show();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your code is inside a handler function or something, here is what I typically do:

```
handler: function(button){
    if(!button.modiwin)
    {
        button.modiwin = Ext.create('widget.window', {
            height: 70,
            width: 110,
            title: 'Editing',
            closable: true,
            autoScroll: false,
            collapsible: true,
            //modal:'True',
            maximizable: false,
            resizable:false,
            items: [mdsavebtn,mddelbtn]
        });
    }
    button.modiwin.setPosition(175,55);
    button.modiwin.show();
}
```

This way, the button can hold on to a reference to the window and always check if it exists before creating it again.

Comment: Even though the button holds a reference to the created window , but it doesn't know when the window was closed and so continues to hold a reference , even after the window was closed .
   So if you try to open it again by clicking the button , nothing comes up .

Comment: You need to set the closeAction to "hide", so the window does not get destroyed.

Answer (score 2):

You could also set the id of the window, and check the WindowManager (using each()) to see if the window is already in the set.  See http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.WindowManager

Comment: Thanks for reply. But i am not closing the previous open window and directly calling function to open new window. for that what need close previous and open new ?

Comment: If you find the window in the set of open windows, you can then close it if you want.

Comment: You don't have to close the previous window. Just skip opening a new window if you detect it's already there.

Answer (score 1):

Add a listener on the `close` event of the window to track the state window. In substance that would give something like the following. You should probably organize your code a little better than in this example, by keeping the window reference in a class property instead of a scope variable like I do for example.

```
var modiwin = null;

function showModiWin() {
    modiwin = Ext.widget('window', {
        height: 70,
        width: 110,
        title: 'Editing',
        closable: true,
        autoScroll: false,
        collapsible: true,
        //modal:'True',
        maximizable: false,
        resizable:false,
        items: [mdsavebtn,mddelbtn]
    });

    modiwin.on('close', function() {
        // ensure the old window is cleaned out (in case its close 
        // action just hides it)
        modiwin.destroy();

        // remember we don't have a window anymore
        modiwin = null;
    });

    modiwin.setPosition(175,55);
    modiwin.show();
}

Ext.widget('button', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    ,text: "Open window"
    ,handler: function() {
        // close the previous window, if any
        if (modiwin) {
            modiwin.close();
        }
        showModiWin();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But i am not closing the previous open window and directly calling function to open new window. for that what need close previous and open new ?